# Could I replace "if" with "that“ in "the only way is if...."?

Tags: conditionals, clauses

> "We're the world's oldest democracy, and **the only way that can come unraveled is if** we have disrespect for institutions that lead to Americans turning on Americans," he said.

What's the way? It's "we have disrespect for institutions". So, Why not just say "the only way.... is that ...."? I think what follows "is" should just be the description of the way. Why is there an extra "if"? I know it forms a conditional clause, but it seems unnecessary.

I also found the sentence "the only way to do that is to speak authentically". There is no "if", and I think it can be said like "to speak authentically is the only way to do that", but could I say "If we have disrespect... is the only way that can come ..."?

I'm confused.

Comment: Looks okay as is. But I'm stuck on "Americans turning on Americans." I already have disrespect for those institutions. Arguing is democratic, turning on, no.

Comment: It's grammatical, but it doesn't mean the same thing as _if_. Not even close.

Comment: As @JohnLawler says, it doesn't mean the same thing as *if.* The function of *if* here, as always, is to remove the supposition that the proposition in the clause is necessarily true. In other words, the writer is implying that it does not necessarily have to be the case that Americans have disrespect for their institutions and turn on each other.

Comment: English prefers verbs to nouns: if we disrespect its institutions. ""have disrespect" *sounds* unidiomatic.

Comment: What happens if you switch word order and consider what 'that can come unraveled only…' changes? Doesn't that clearly suggest that 'if' is the only real choice?

Answer (score 1):

If you say *the only way is **that** we have respect*, it is likely to be read as you asserting that "we have respect".

*The only way is if we have respect* keeps the clause as hypothetical (or at least conditional).

Comment: All you guys might be entirely correct in strict rules of grammar and every other view of speech but two things:

'We're the world's oldest democracy' threw common sense out of the window. So what?

More importantly, if the Question was Asked in English Language Learners, the detailed Answers and Comments given would be appropriate, though in my view it's unlikely anyone there would take the trouble…

Here, unless the cited speaker is supposed to have unusually high standards, I suggest very few native readers would understand any relevant difference, even if they somehow saw it.

Comment: I'm with you in general, @RobbieGoodwin - "strict rules of grammar" are mostly hogwash. But this native speaker finds _the only way that can come unraveled is that we have disrespect_ distinctly odd.

Comment: I agree, but you're not the average man on the Clapham Omnibus.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin We aren't lawyers, though.

Comment: It means it is mostly a legal term (coming from an actual court case) referring to a reasonable person and not to Mr. and Mrs. Average.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry and you seem to be missing two vital points.

First, if you want to cite a case, cite it. You seem to be claiming that a case existed, with no supporting reference. How is that acceptable?

Second, what response do you think you will get from asking any jurist what difference there is between 'a reasonable person' and 'Mr or Mrs Average'?

Try it, why not?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The term "man on the Clapham Omnibus" comes from a British court case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_on_the_Clapham_omnibus

Comment: @Lambie, I think you are falling prey to the etymological fallacy. The meaning of a word or phrase lies in how it is used and understood, not in its origin. The iWeb corpus has 93 instances of "Clapham Omnibus", and inspection indicates that a minority are in a legal context.

Comment: @ColinFine No, it is you who did not understand **my joke**. Robbie said: I agree, but you're not the average man on the Clapham Omnibus. And I said: We aren't lawyers, though.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks and like Colin, I did not understand that. Please, how was it a joke?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin We aren't lawyers and if we were, this would be about a reasonable man, not an average man: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasonable_person. Once you explain everything, the charm is lost.

Comment: @Lambie: I understood your joke perfectly well.

Comment: @ColinFine I was addressing Robbie, not you. That said, since you understood it, then, I couldn't have "fallen prey to etymological fallacy", could I? Phrases have origins **and meanings**, not etymologies, to be accurate about this.